# Какова структура файла байткода CPython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, байткод, python-internals

Пытаюсь разобраться в структуре скомпилированного байт-кода CPython.
Допустим, у меня есть файл `foo.py` следующего содержания:

```
def hello(name):
    print("Hello, %s" % name)
```

Скомпилированный `__pycache__\foo.cpython-35.pyc` выглядит так:

[image: байткод]

Дальше что я понял:

- `16 0d 0d 0a` - это [магическое число](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)#.D0.A1.D0.B8.D0.B3.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D0.B0_.D0.B4.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85)
- `06 e2 7f 57` - дата последнего изменения
- `31 00 00 00` - размер файла (должен быть - хотя в файле 216 байт, так что я не знаю, что это за размер на самом деле)
- следующие 22 байта (`e3 00 00 00 ... 00 00 00 73`) - не знаю для чего
- `10 00 00 00` - видимо размер кода модуля (но тогда получается что предыдущий символ должен быть типом, а это `73` - код строкового типа)
- `64 00 00`, `64 01 00` - `LOAD_CONST(0); LOAD_CONST(1)`,
  где константа 0 - `code object` функции, константа 1 - её имя (`"hello"`)
- `84 00 00` - `MAKE_FUNCTION(0)`, только я так и не понял, зачем нужен аргумент этого опкода
- `5a 00 00` - `STORE_NAME(0)`, где имя 0 - имя функции (`"hello"`)
- `64 02 00 53` - `LOAD_CONST(2); RETURN_VALUE`, где константа 2 - `None` (правда не совсем понятно зачем модулю возвращать что-то)
- `29 03` - кортеж констант модуля: `(<code object hello>, "hello", None)`
- следующие 18 байт (`74 00 00 64 ... 64 00 00 53`) - код функции `hello` (тот который `hello.__code__.co_code`)
- `29 02` - кортеж констант функции: `(None, "Hello, %s")`
- `4e` - тип константы `NONE`
- `7a 09` - тип строковой константы (`SHORT_ASCII`) и длина строки `"Hello, %s"` (9 символов)
- `48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 25 73` - строка `"Hello, %s"`
- `29 01` - кортеж имён функции: `("print",)`
- `da 05` - здесь вроде должен быть один из строковых типов, но вместо него несуществующий тип `da`; `05` - длина строка
- `70 72 69 6e 74` - имя функции `print`
- `29 01` - кортеж имён локальных переменных: `("name",)`
- `da 04` - опять неизвестный тип `da` и длина строки `04`
- `6e 61 6d 65` - имя переменной `name`
- `a9 00 72 03 00 00 00` - не понял
- `fa 06` - ещё один непонятный тип `fa` и длина строки `06`
- `66 6f 6f 2e 70 79` - имя файла модуля (`foo.py`)
- `da 05` - непонятный тип `da` и длина строки `05`
- `68 65 6c 6c 6f` - имя функции `hello` (правда нет объявления кортежа имён модуля или вроде того)
- следующие 17 байт (`01 00 00 00 ... 00 00 00 4e`) - не понял
- `29 01` - какой-то кортеж длиной в один элемент
- `72 ...` - константа типа `ref` (что это за тип?)
- `da 08` - снова загадочный типа `da` и длина строки 08
- `3c 6d 6f 64 75 6c 65 3e` - строка `"<module>"` (зачем?)
- `01 ...` - дальше не знаю что

Помогите восполнить пробелы. Если бы мне надо было просто узнать значение какой-нибудь константы, то мне бы имеющихся знаний хватило. Но я пытаюсь написать интерпретатор байт-кода Python, так что мне надо полностью разобраться со структурой `.pyc`-файлов.

Comment: ты не думал склонить репозиторий питона и посмотреть как там это делается? на опкоды поглядеть и т.д.?

Comment: @strangeqargo, разбираться в сорцах - путь истинного джедая, не каждому под Силу, особенно если нужно узнать только структуру.

Comment: Вряд ли есть шансы уложиться в формат ответа - тут по идее очень много описывать нужно.

Comment: @strangeqargo, ну, в общем-то многое из того что я написал выше я узнал из исходников. Просто иногда не знаешь где именно дальше искать, и тогда ищешь везде подряд, а это получается очень долго.

Comment: ты мог бы, например, изменить исходники так, чтобы они к каждому опкоду писали комменты (вызываемая функция и т.д.) и выдавали на выходе txt файл, и да, я уверен что есть py-дизассемблеры, смотрел?

Comment: @m9_psy, может есть хотя бы ссылки на статьи по теме. Потому что я ни в официальной документации, ни в гугле не нашёл полного описания структуры, только непосредственно байт-кода функции, без описания способа хранения констант, имён переменных и т. д.

Comment: можно начать со стандартного модуля `dis` (дизассемблер). Related: [The structure of .pyc files](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html). Можно также посмотреть как [`codetransformer` работает с байткодом во время исполнения](https://github.com/llllllllll/codetransformer), сравнить как похожие вещи [`macropy` делает с помощью манипуляции AST](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy)

Comment: Есть ответ на английской версии stackoverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682675/python-virtual-machine-architecture-diagrams-references

Comment: Байткод очень напоминает Java байткод. питон базируется на java. 90% что файлы идентичны, могут отличатся сигнатурой или отступлениями.  Информация есть тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358121/java-bytecode-specification может позже сверю.

Comment: @nick_n_a, Python не базируется на Java и байт-код CPython очень сильно отличается от байт-кода JVM. Не надо выдумывать то, чего не знаете.

Comment: Я бы начал изучение с такой штуки, как Python Byte Code Specification (вряд ли без спецификации его создавали). Например: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html Как тут правильно заметили, вряд ли удастся пройти мимо анализа исходников Python, потому что "Python bytecode is considered an implementation detail and not officially supported or documented". Т.е. - спека есть, но она не публичная. Более того, раз она непубличная, значит, авторам ничего не мешает изменить ее в любой момент.

Comment: А похожий вопрос на англоязычной SO закрыли как "не подходящий под формат вопрос/ответ": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808387/writing-my-own-python-parser-and-interpreter

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*История длинная - можно поставить чайку. Также у меня нет возможности копировать все из документации в ответ, так что документацию придется читать самому. Также не будет экспериментов с [dis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) - предполагается, что автор вопроса уже наигрался с ним и решил копнуть глубже.*

Вопрос объемный, но так как он пользуется популярностью, я немного коснусь этой темы для одной выбранной реализации и одной выбранной версии - `CPython 3.6.1` - эта версия, потому что она последняя и ответ устареет позднее, и потому что в вопросе явно указана версия 3.5.

В общем-то в последних версиях довольно легко разобраться, что к чему - нет никаких сложностей, которые могут сорвать вам колпак. Исходной точкой будет модуль [py_compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html). Почему с нее, а не с C исходников? - потому что вот что говорит документация о нем: `Этот модуль предоставляет функцию для генерации байт-кода из исходников`. То, что доктор прописал.

Также заранее напишем тестовый пример, который и будет подвергнут разбору и определим его в отдельный файл `test.py`.

```
import time


def my_gen():
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(1)
        yield i**2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for elem in my_gen():
        print(elem)
```

Теперь в основном файле мы можем сгенерировать байткод вот так:

```
import py_compile

py_compile.compile("test.py", "test.pyc")
```

Расширение `*.pyc` - всего лишь расширение, соглашение о наименовании и может быть каким угодно, главное - это содержимое.

Запустить можно как обычно - `python test.pyc`.

Теперь самое время обратить внимание на функцию, которая и сгенерировала байткод. Исходники вы можете посмотреть самостоятельно, я приведу краткую выдержку:

1. Первое, что там происходит - это определение пути и имени для выходного байткода. Мы указали это явно. Если нет, то путь определяется согласно [PEP 3147](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/)/[PEP 488](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0488/) и еще и от версии зависит.
2. Исходник в виде текста преобразуется в байты. За это отвечает еще модуль - [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib), а точнее класс [`importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader). Внезапно, весь код, который там выполняется - это

   ```
   with _io.FileIO(path, 'r') as file:
       return file.read()
   ```

   то есть исходник просто читается. В нашем коде это выглядит как:

   ```
   loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('<py_compile>', file)
   source_bytes = loader.get_data(file)
   ```
3. Исходники преобразовываются в AST - Абстрактное Синтаксическое Дерево. Невозможно тут написать, какой путь проходит исходник через череду всяких функций и проверок, но вкратце: вызывается функция [compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile):

   ```
   code1 = compile(source_bytes, file, mode='exec', dont_inherit=True)
   code = loader.source_to_code(source_bytes, file)

   print(code, type(code))

   print(code == code1)
   ```

   Выше в коде я копировал их исходников `py_compile` (`loader.source_to_code`) и написал сам с использованием функции `compile` - результат в простом случае одинаков. Результатом явился экземпляр класса из модуля [`code`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#module-code).
4. Наконец, самое главное - преобразование AST в байткод. В py_compile это делается так:

   ```
   source_stats = loader.path_stats(file)
   bytecode = importlib._bootstrap_external._code_to_bytecode(
           code, source_stats['mtime'], source_stats['size'])
   ```

   `sourcestats` выглядит как-то так: `{'mtime': 1493229661.7715623, 'size': 180}`. `mtime` - это время изменения исходника, выраженное в каком-то особоточном timestamp'е. Пригодится еще далее.

   Содержание `code_to_bytecode`:

   ```
   data = bytearray(MAGIC_NUMBER)
   data.extend(_w_long(mtime))
   data.extend(_w_long(source_size))
   data.extend(marshal.dumps(code))
   ```

   Я был удивлен, но само преобразование в байткод занимает в общем-то 4 строчки. `MAGIC_NUMBER` - волшебное словцо, новое для каждой новой версии. Для 3.6.1 (Python 3.6rc1) - это `(3379).to_bytes(2, 'little') + b'\r\n'`. Список всех волшебных словец можно найти в файле `importlib/_bootstrap_external.py`. Обратите внимание, что помимо числа туда еще засовывается перевод каретки. Функция `_w_long` - это `(int(x) & 0xFFFFFFFF).to_bytes(4, 'little')`. - можно проверить HEX редактором фактическое содержание .pyc файла - все совпадает. То есть сам код начинается после `2 + 2 + 4 + 4` байтов. Это все мелочи, настоящая цель - модель [marshal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html#marshal.dumps) и функция [dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html#marshal.dumps). `marshal` - это `модуль, содержащий функции, которые могут читать и писать значение переменных в бинарном формате. Формате специфичен для Python, но независим от архитектуры конечной машины`.
5. Дальше, к сожалению, на питоне ехать не получиться, придется идти в исходники исходников: можно проследить за судьбой объекта в `marshal.dumps`, но в конечном итоге объект бьется на байты [вот этой функцией](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/marshal.c#L334). Она длинная, но *относительно* простая. Маршал может много всяких объектов засунуть в файл, но нас интересует объект типа `code` (его ему передали) - для этого есть [специальная проверка](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/marshal.c#L532) на то, не является ли переданный объект кодом. Как видно из этой функции, безусловно пишется много какой информации - тип операции (op_code), аргументы, значения аргументов самые простые из этого списка. Что конкретно означают эти переменные, можно посмотреть (там комментов навалили сполна) в определении структуры PyCodeObject в [файле code.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Include/code.h#L21)
6. Еще, в общем-то, не все. Все только начинается. Мы можем посмотреть, ЧТО КОНКРЕТНО, по байтам, пишется в pyc файл и не придется лазить в C. Дело в том, что все нужные аттрибуты есть у питоновского объекта `code`. Я расположил аргументы в том порядке, в каком они пишутся в pyc:

   ```
   args = ['co_argcount', 'co_kwonlyargcount', 'co_nlocals', 'co_stacksize', 'co_flags',  'co_code', 'co_consts', 
           'co_names', 'co_varnames', 'co_freevars', 'co_cellvars', 'co_filename', 'co_name', 'co_firstlineno', 
           'co_lnotab']

   for arg in args:
       print(arg, getattr(code, arg, None))
   ```

   Распечатав на экране значение аргументов, а также посчитав смещения (1 вызов `w_long` пишет 4 байта, `W_TYPE` пишет 1 байт) вы можете с легкостью, с помощью HEX редактора посмотреть что и куда пишется. Проанализировать co_code вы уже можете с помощью dis - в новых версиях у него появился козырный метод [get_instructions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.get_instructions):

   ```
   for instruction in dis.get_instructions(code):
       print(instruction)
   ```

   В нем также есть и байтовое смещение, и код операнда и все, что может понадобиться.
7. Для закрепления прочитанного можно своими руками полностью раскукожить `pyc` файл. Не буду писать весь парсер - дюже затратно, но из того, что написано уже можно написать парсер полностью:

   ```
   from io import BytesIO
   import struct
   import datetime

   byte1_little = b"<c"
   byte2_little = b"<h"
   byte4_little = b"<I"

   byte1_big = b">c"
   byte2_big = b">h"
   byte4_big = b">I"

   INTEGER_TYPE = int.from_bytes(b'i', 'little')
   CODE_TYPE = int.from_bytes(b'c', 'little')
   SHORT_TUPLE_TYPE = int.from_bytes(b')', 'little')
   NONE_TYPE = int.from_bytes(b'N', 'little')


   def parse_string(raw_bytes):
       # Наш рулевой тут - https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/marshal.c#L427
       # Байтик на тип, четверочку на размер
       SIZE = int.from_bytes(raw_bytes.read(4), 'little')
       print("BYTES TO READ: ", SIZE)
       s = raw_bytes.read(SIZE)
       return s


   def parse_code(raw_bytes):
       CO_ARGCOUNT = struct.unpack(byte4_little, raw_bytes.read(4))[0]
       co_kwonlyargcount = struct.unpack(byte4_little,     raw_bytes.read(4))[0]
       CO_NLOCALS = struct.unpack(byte4_little, raw_bytes.read(4))[0]
       CO_STACKSIZE = struct.unpack(byte4_little, raw_bytes.read(4))[0]
       CO_FLAGS = struct.unpack(byte4_little, raw_bytes.read(4))[0]
       print("CODE STATS:", CO_ARGCOUNT, co_kwonlyargcount, CO_NLOCALS, CO_STACKSIZE, CO_FLAGS)
       CODE_TYPE = raw_bytes.read(1)
       # Тип строка
       assert CODE_TYPE == b's'
       CODE_ITSELF = parse_string(raw_bytes)
       return CODE_ITSELF


   def parse_long(raw_bytes):
       VALUE = int.from_bytes(raw_bytes.read(4), 'little')
       print("LONG VALUE:", VALUE)
       return VALUE


   def parse_none(raw_bytes):
       # Уже отпрасили
       return None


   def parse_tuple(raw_bytes):
       # Размер у маленького - 1 байт, а не 4
       # https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/marshal.c#L471
       SIZE = int.from_bytes(raw_bytes.read(1), 'little')
       print("TUPLE LEN:", SIZE)
       # Следующий тип - SHORT_TUPLE. Также по аналогии
       for index in range(SIZE):
           NEXT_TYPE = int.from_bytes(raw_bytes.read(1), 'little')
           if NEXT_TYPE == INTEGER_TYPE or NEXT_TYPE == INTEGER_TYPE | 128:
               print("LONG TYPE")
               parse_long(raw_bytes)
           # None 1 байт
           elif NEXT_TYPE == NONE_TYPE:
               print("NONE TYPE")
               parse_none(raw_bytes)
           # code
           elif NEXT_TYPE == CODE_TYPE or NEXT_TYPE == CODE_TYPE | 128:
               print("CODE TYPE")
               parse_code(raw_bytes)
           elif NEXT_TYPE == SHORT_TUPLE_TYPE:
               parse_tuple(raw_bytes)


   with open("test.pyc", "rb") as f:
       raw_bytes = BytesIO(f.read())

   MAGIC_NUMBER = struct.unpack(byte2_little, raw_bytes.read(2))[0]
   assert MAGIC_NUMBER == 3379
   # пропускаем \r\n
   raw_bytes.read(2)
   TIMESTAMP = struct.unpack(byte4_little, raw_bytes.read(4))[0]
   print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(TIMESTAMP))
   SIZE = struct.unpack(byte4_little, raw_bytes.read(4))[0]
   print(SIZE)
   OBJ_TYPE = int.from_bytes(raw_bytes.read(1), 'little')
   # Объект типа TYPE_CODE - см. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/marshal.c#L46
   # Флаг 128 выставляется в функции https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/marshal.c#L288
   assert OBJ_TYPE == CODE_TYPE | 128
   parse_code(raw_bytes)
   NEXT_TYPE = int.from_bytes(raw_bytes.read(1), 'little')
   # Small tuple
   if NEXT_TYPE == SHORT_TUPLE_TYPE:
       parse_tuple(raw_bytes)
   ```

   Код несколько неполный, обрабатывается только несколько типов, но, надеюсь, сама идея понятна - этот код - зеркальное отражение функции `dumps` - только там использовался `w_object` (write object) и свои записывалки для простых типов, вам же нужно `r_object` (read object) и читалки для простых. [r_object уже написан](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/marshal.c#L910), остается только его внимательно прочитать.

Comment: Когда натыкаюсь на ответ, каждый раз думаю, при чем тут чайка?

Comment: @insolor Не чайка, а чаёк )

Comment: @CrazyElf, это понятно, но почему-то каждый раз читается как "можно поставить чАйку")