# Python, склеивание файлов pyc

Tags: python

Разбираю структуру .pyc файла
Появился конкретный вопрос, можно ли объединить 2 .pyc файла?
file1.pyc содержит такой код
`print(1)`
file2.pyc содержит такой код
`print(2)`

Первые 4 байта, это Magic Number, - `imp.get_magic()`, это число отвечает за текущую версию компилятора.
Далее 6 байт это `timestamp`

```
def wr_long(f, x):
   f.write(chr( x        & 0xff))
   f.write(chr((x >> 8)  & 0xff))
   f.write(chr((x >> 16) & 0xff))
   f.write(chr((x >> 24) & 0xff))
```

Ну и собственно мой код

```
file1 = open('3.pyc', 'rb+') 
file1.seek(8)
file1code = file1.read()
file1.close()

with open('comple.pyc', 'wb+') as milf:
    milf.write(imp.get_magic()) # Магическое число
    milf.write("\0\0\0\0") # timestamp-заглушка
    milf.write(file1code) # код файла к которому пытаюсь джойнить
    milf.seek(14) # Смещение на 14 байтов, пробовал такой диапазон(0-70)
    milf.write(compile('print(4)', "", 'exec').co_code) # 2-ой файл .pyc
```

Comment: наверное можно через какой-то стандартный модуль получить питоничий код из pyc, а после его обратно в pyc скомпилировать

Comment: @Abyx, мне не нужно класть файлы в .zip, мне конкретно нужно получить из двух файлов один, я выше привёл наработку.

Comment: @gil9red, pyc файл может быть обфусцирован.

Comment: @Abyx я знаю что python умеет брать из zip'a, у меня стоит конкретная цель, склеить 2 .pyc файла, с сохранением функционала.

Comment: Возможно поможет [Какова структура файла байткода CPython?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/552427/Какова-структура-файла-байткода-cpython) - там есть указания на то, как определить длину следующего участка - CODE в вашем случае и можно попробовать просто склеить два "code" и поменять их размер, но совсем не факт, что оно работать после этого будет.

Comment: я бы попробовал склеить два .py файла, а потом из него получить .pyc файл. Задача склеить 2 .py файла кажется мне более простой, нежели склеивать .pyc файлы. Понятно что в общем случае эту задачу очень сложно (или невозможно) решить, но в каких то тривиальных случаях думаю реально. И скорее всего это наложит ограничения на структуру .py файлов. Вот почва для размышлений https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380763/python-merge-py-part-files-into-one-py-file

Comment: неймспейсы то разные... я пробовал, но всё не то.
самое близкое по смыслу  - это include на cython. но это уже другой язык