# Как устроены .pyc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, компиляция, байткод

Здравствуйте! Допустим, есть такой код:

```
x = 10
```

нужно получить байткод, который ему соответствует.
Попробуем его скомпилировать:

```
from dis import dis
dis('x=10')
```

Получим:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (10)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (x)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Или, так (что почти то же самое):

```
from dis import Bytecode
bc = Bytecode('x=10')
list(bc.codeobj.co_code)
[100, 0, 90, 0, 100, 1, 83, 0]
```

В последнем байткоде потеряна информация о константах, при том, что есть `LOAD_CONST` (100).

Попробуем скомпилировать файл с помощью `compileall`:

```
>> python -m compileall ./
Listing './'...
Compiling './set.py'...
```

Получим:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 40 00 00
00 73 08 00 00 00 64 00 5A 00 64 01 53 00 29 02    
E9 0A 00 00 00 4E 29 01 DA 01 78 A9 00 72 03 00   
00 00 72 03 00 00 00 FA 08 2E 2F 73 65 74 2E 70
79 DA 08 3C 6D 6F 64 75 6C 65 3E 01 00 00 00 73    
00 00 00 00
```

Найти в этом коде предыдущий мне не удалось.

Как это можно объяснить?
Где вообще можно почитать про то, как устроен `.pyc`?

Хочу написать свою маленькую ВМ для Python.

Comment: Как минимум `64 00 5A 00 64 01 53 00` это `[100, 0, 90, 0, 100, 1, 83, 0]`

Comment: А беглый поиск по документации говорит, что нолик у LOAD_CONST ссылается на первую константу, хранящуюся в co_consts

Comment: @andreymal да, действительно, плохо искал. Про нолик в `LOAD_CONST ` я знаю, непонятно только, что из файла выше является таблицей констант.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Какова структура файла байткода CPython?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/552427/23044)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pyc-файл состоит из

- Четырёхбайтового магического номера
- Четырёхбайтовой метки времени
- Четырёх байт хранящих размер исходного файла
- Сериализованного [объекта кода](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#code-objects)

Магический номер - это два байта уникальных для каждой версии интерпретатора и два байта `0d0a`. Байты `0d0a` - это символ возврата каретки и перевода строки, защищающие файл от повреждения в случае редактирования в текстовом режиме.

Метка времени хранит время последнего изменения исходника, по которому сгенерирован pyc-файл.

С размером, уверен, всё очевидно и каких-либо уточнений не требует.

Остальная часть файла - это результат выполнения [marshal.dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html#marshal.dump) на объекте кода, который в свою очередь является результатом компиляции исходника.

"Дизассемблировать" pyc-файл можно этим скриптом:

```
import dis, marshal, struct, sys, time, types
from codecs import encode


def show_file(fname):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as fh:
        magic = fh.read(4)
        moddate = fh.read(4)
        filesz = fh.read(4)
        modtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(struct.unpack('=L', moddate)[0]))
        filesz = struct.unpack('=L', filesz)
        print('magic {!s}'.format(encode(magic, 'hex').decode()))
        print('moddate {!s} ({!s})'.format(encode(moddate, 'hex').decode(), modtime))
        print('file size {:d}'.format(*filesz))
        code = marshal.load(fh)
        show_code(code)


def show_code(code, indent=''):
    print('{!s}code'.format(indent))
    indent += '   '
    print('{!s}argcount {:d}'.format(indent, code.co_argcount))
    print('{!s}nlocals {:d}'.format(indent, code.co_nlocals))
    print('{!s}stacksize {:d}'.format(indent, code.co_stacksize))
    print('{!s}flags {:0>4x}'.format(indent, code.co_flags))
    show_hex('code', code.co_code, indent=indent)
    dis.disassemble(code)
    print('{!s}consts'.format(indent))
    for const in code.co_consts:
        if type(const) == types.CodeType:
            show_code(const, indent + '   ')
        else:
            print('   {!s}{!r}'.format(indent, const))
    print('{!s}names {!r}'.format(indent, code.co_names))
    print('{!s}varnames {!r}'.format(indent, code.co_varnames))
    print('{!s}freevars {!r}'.format(indent, code.co_freevars))
    print('{!s}cellvars {!r}'.format(indent, code.co_cellvars))
    print('{!s}filename {!r}'.format(indent, code.co_filename))
    print('{!s}name {!r}'.format(indent, code.co_name))
    print('{!s}firstlineno {:d}'.format(indent, code.co_firstlineno))
    show_hex('lnotab', code.co_lnotab, indent=indent)


def show_hex(label, h, indent):
    h = encode(h, 'hex').decode()
    if len(h) < 60:
        print('{!s}{!s} {!s}'.format(indent, label, h))
    else:
        print ('{!s}{!s}'.format(indent, label))
        for i in range(0, len(h), 60):
            print('{!s}   {!s}'.format(indent, h[i:i+60]))


show_file(sys.argv[1])
```

Запуск его на pyc-файле этого скрипта

```
a, b = 1, 0
if a or b:
    print('Hello', a)
```

даст такой вывод

```
magic 330d0d0a
moddate 1094a85a (Wed Mar 14 11:16:32 2018)
files sz 48
code
   argcount 0
   nlocals 0
   stacksize 3
   flags 0040
   code
      64045c025a005a01650073106501721a6502640265008302010064035300
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               4 ((1, 0))
              2 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              4 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (b)

  2           8 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             10 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        16
             12 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             14 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       26

  3     >>   16 LOAD_NAME                2 (print)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 ('Hello')
             20 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             24 POP_TOP
        >>   26 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
   consts
      1
      0
      'Hello'
      None
      (1, 0)
   names ('a', 'b', 'print')
   varnames ()
   freevars ()
   cellvars ()
   filename 'D:\\playground\\python\\test.py'
   name '<module>'
   firstlineno 1
   lnotab 08010801
```

Ответ написан на основе [этой статьи](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html).

Comment: `ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)` -- скопировал код из ответа: выполнил `-mcompileall .`, запустил `nedbatchelor.py __pycache__/sergey-gornostaev*.pyc`

Comment: @jfs странно. Это код из исходной статьи, немного подправленный, чтобы работал на Python 3. Прежде, чем отправить ответ, я его проверил на своей машине.У меня он такое выдаёт только при запуске на Python 2 или попытке прочитать pyc-файл второго Python'а.

Comment: я запускал, используя текущую версию python из github. Проверка на фиксированной версии работает: Скомпилировать: `docker run --rm -v $PWD:/tmp python:3.6.4 python -mcompileall /tmp` Прочитать: `docker run --rm -v $PWD:/tmp python:3.6.4 python /tmp/nedbatchelor.py /tmp/__pycache__/sergey-gornostaev-example.cpython-36.pyc`

Comment: @jfs теперь жутко любопытно, что изменилось. Но боюсь, что если начну разбираться, меня точно уволят.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev У меня тоже ваш код не работает.

Comment: @Rennorb какая у вас версия Python?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev 3.6.1

Comment: @Rennorb чем дальше, тем страннее. У меня работает на 3.4.2, 3.5.3 и 3.6.3.

Comment: @Rennorb а можете pyc-файл скинуть? Я бы сравнил с теми которые генерируют интерпретаторы на моей машине, а то мне это покоя не даёт.

Comment: У меня тоже фиаско:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "show_code.py", line 55, in <module>
    show_file(sys.argv[1])
  File "show_code.py", line 16, in show_file
    show_code(code)
  File "show_code.py", line 23, in show_code
    print('{!s}argcount {:d}'.format(indent, code.co_argcount))
AttributeError: 'ellipsis' object has no attribute 'co_argcount'